# Não consigo compilar uma classe Java que instância outa classe Java

Tags: java, cmd

É o seguinte, eu tenho duas classes: Conta.java e Programa1.java a ideia é a classe Programa1 criar uma instância de Conta e usá-la dentro do programa mas não estou conseguindo compilar a classe Programa1 pelo prompt (Não estou usando IDE).

Conta.java:

```
package generico;

class Conta {
    int numero;
    String titular;
    double saldo;
}
```

Programa1.java:

```
package generico;

class Programa1{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Conta minhaConta;
        minhaConta = new Conta();

        minhaConta.titular = "Duke";
        minhaConta.saldo = 1000.0;

        System.out.println("Saldo atual: " + minhaConta.saldo)
    }
}
```

Aparece o seguinte erro quando tento compilar Programa1.java:

```
Programa1.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
                Conta minhaConta;
                ^
  symbol:   class Conta
  location: class Programa1
Programa1.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
                minhaConta = new Conta();
                                 ^
  symbol:   class Conta
  location: class Programa1
2 errors
error: compilation failed
```

Comment: Calde o "public" no nome das classes?

Comment: Remove o package q funciona.

Answer (score 6):

Se você está executando ambas as classes da mesma pasta do sistema operacional através do prompt de comando(Windows) ou console(linux), não precisa informar package. Remova `package generico` que o código funciona perfeitamente.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Eu uso o Windows 10. Vejo que no seu gif está funcionando certinho do jeito que eu queria, mas aqui, mesmo com as alterações não funcionou. Estou vendo que meu problema é mais embaixo pelo seguinte: Quando vou executar uma classe java eu não consigo fazer usando "java MinhaClasse" pois da o erro:
Error: Could not find or load main class MinhaClasse Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MinhaClasse. 
Tenho que fazer "java MinhaClasse.java"

Comment: @Juviosa se remover o que eu falei na resposta e executar direto do diretorio como mostra o gif, nao da erro. Se der, nao é problema do java, e sim de como ta configurado o classpath no seu computador, o que ja é um problema bem diferente da pergunta

Comment: Eu removi o que você falou. E sim, tô achando que o erro tá no classpath. Obrigada pela ajuda!